# How to find jQuery DropDownCheckList selected items from an outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function does kind of what I want in that it retrieves the values of the selected dropdown menu:

```
$(function() {
$("#s1").dropdownchecklist();

$('#s1').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
});
```

My problem is I don't want this to occur on Change, I want to get the selected values from inside another function that is being called when my slider moves. So, my question is how can I assign the checked values from #s1.dropdownchecklist to var checkedValuesFromDropdownChecklist?

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
change: function(event, ui) {
    if (event.originalEvent) {
        //manual change
      RunThisFunction(ui.value,checkedValuesFromDropdownChecklist);
    }
},
orientation: "horizontal",
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 100,
value: 10,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidecreate", function( event, ui ) {
} );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RunThisFunction(ui.value, $('#s1').val());
```

Comment: $('#s1').val() returns undefined

Comment: But `$('#s1').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});` doesn't?

Comment: yeah, i will verify one sec

Comment: ok i solved the problem thanks to everyones help. #s1 is a class not ID.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.val` to access the current value of the dropdown.

```
var selectedValue = $('#s1').val();

console.log(selectedValue);

 RunThisFunction(ui.value, $('#s1').val());
```